# How to keep stacking tensors in Tensorflow

Tags: arrays, tensorflow, stack, append, shapes

The Goal is to Append 2 Tensors with one matching shape

```
import tensorflow as tf 
x = tf.constant([1, 4]) 
y = tf.constant([2, 5]) 
z = tf.constant([3, 6]) 
res = tf.stack([x, y],axis=0)
print(res)
->tf.Tensor(
  [[1 4]
  [2 5]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
print(z)
->tf.Tensor([3 6], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
result = tf.stack((res, z),axis=1)
->tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [2,2] != values[1].shape = [2] [Op:Pack] name: stack
```

what I expected

```
print(result)
->->tf.Tensor(
  [[1 4]
  [2 5]
  [3,6]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
```

i tried different combination of concat and stack. How is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `tf.stack` works because all the input tensors `x, y, z` have the same shape `(2,)`. The second `tf.stack` will not work as we are dealing with differently shaped Tensors.

In order to join them, you can use `tf.concat` but with adjusted Tensor's shape:

```py
# res is shape (2, 2)
z = tf.expand_dims(z, axis=0)     # Shape is now (1, 2) instead of (2,)
result = tf.concat((res, z), axis=0)     # Shape match except in axis 0

print(result)
```

This will return

```py
tf.Tensor(
[[1 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 6]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)
```